# Servidor de correos funcion mail no responde al activar TLS en el servidor

Tags: php, mail, tls

Activamos tls en el servidor y ya no se envían los correos
se usa framework cake
Esta es la función que se usa para probar el envío de correo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La configuración actual de recordatorios es

```
   'recordatorios' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
        'port' => xxx,
        'tls' => true,
        'client' => null,
        'username' => 'xxx@xxxxxxxx.xxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    ]
```

Nota: se cambiaron los datos de configuración por xxxxx para este ejemplo

La duda es como indicar que está activo tls, nosotros lo tenemos como null antes de activar tls y cuando se activo ya dejo de enviar correos... no se que se deba cambiar, busque algunos ejemplos pero solo encuentro con php mailer.

Editado 2020-09-15 logs

Estos son los logs que me marca al tratar de correr la funcion de enviar correo

2020-09-15 08:47:33 Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException] SMTP server did not accept the connection or trying to connect to non TLS SMTP server using TLS.
Request URL: /recordatorios/envia_correo_testing
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php(159): Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport->_connect()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Email/Email.php(1301): Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport->send(Object(Cake\Network\Email\Email))
#2 /var/www/html/src/Controller/RecordatoriosController.php(3578): Cake\Network\Email\Email->send('mensaje de prue...')
#3 [internal function]: App\Controller\RecordatoriosController->envia_correo_testing()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(411): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(114): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\RecordatoriosController))
#7 /var/www/html/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#8 {main}

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes partir de lo que veas para phpMailer. El fondo está en que tienes que indicar un puerto específico diferente al puerto estándar SMTP, además de configurar tu _sender_ para que incluya ciertas cabeceras en la petición y se autentique correctamente. Necesitas revisar cómo funciona la autenticación en el servidor SMTP (tiene OAuth y debes crear una app password? Por que puerto está escuchando?) Por último, tienes que revisar tus logs para ver qué error está saliendo ahora mismo

Comment: PD. Para TLS se suele usar 587 pero no sobra confirmar. Con los hallazgos adicionales que veas en los logs, por favor edita tu pregunta e inclúyelos. Y procura seguir añadiendo todo como texto para poder ayudarte mejor :)

Comment: gracias Alfabravo, efectivamente esta en el puesto 587 y sorry por la imagen... intente escribir todo en texto pero no me dejaba publicar la pregunta porque decía que era más codigo que texto.